# Boost log - cleanup & shutdown

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I have an initialization function which sets up boost log via `add_common_attributes()`, `register_simple_formatter_factory()`, `register_sink_factory()` and `init_from_stream()` (all are functions within `namespace ::boost::log`)

I want to be able to tear down the types I've registered later. It appears easy enough to remove the sinks and unregister attributes using the logging core. But there does not appear to be a way to tear down the registered formatters nor the registered sink factories. There also does not appear to be a way to cleanly tear down the logging core.

Am I missing something? Is there an example of doing this?

I'm originally using `boost 1.55` however I've also looked through `1.57` and `1.58` to no avail.

Ultimately what I need to be able to do is create effectively a wrapper library which can be loaded from multiple applications to provide consistent logging without code duplication to set up. I need the ability to set up and tear down `boost::log` as part of unit testing the features and different configurations.